# How to add a frame to the end of a video without re-encoding in C#?

Tags: python, c#, video

I am working on a C# project that requires adding a custom frame/image to the end of a video without going through the entire re-encoding process, as it may lead to loss of quality and consumes more time.

I have already explored some libraries like FFmpeg and AForge.NET, but I couldn't find a straightforward way to achieve this without re-encoding the entire video.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
// My attempt to append a frame to the end of the video using FFmpeg wrapper for C#
// This code re-encodes the entire video, which I want to avoid.

// [FFmpeg initialization and setup]

string videoFilePath = "path/to/my/video.mp4";
string frameImagePath = "path/to/my/frame.png";
string outputFilePath = "path/to/my/output.mp4";

var ffmpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
ffmpeg.ConcatMedia(new[] { videoFilePath, frameImagePath }, outputFilePath);
```

Is there any way to directly append a frame to the end of the video without re-encoding the whole video? It's crucial for my application to preserve the original video's quality.

Edit: Video and image are the same as resolution.

Edit2: I also can accept doing this using python.

Edit3: I also can accept ffmpeg and creating video from images.

Comment: You mentioned creating video from images. It’s easy to do that in C# using the LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK. (Disclosure: I work for the its vendor) This [forum post](https://leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t11084-) explains 2 approaches depending on the location of images (disk files vs bitmaps loaded in memory). Regarding keeping quality, the SDK allows saving the video either uncompressed, or using any available codec. With many codecs, you can control the parameters to minimize loss of quality. If you’d like to try the SDK, there’s a [free evaluation here](https://leadtools.com/downloads)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer:
What you're trying to do works with uncompressed and sequential data, but if you want to append new frames to an existing compressed video (e.g. `.mp4` or `.webm`), you have to re-encode it to update its headers and compressed contents.
You could export everything to an image sequence, then merge everything back together with the new frame, but that would still require re-encoding.

Comment: So can i do it with for example avi format?

Comment: @helloworld AVI yes, it's uncompressed.

Comment: @SNBS So how can i do this?

Comment: See the answer from @john-janzen
The command worked for me.

Comment: should be possible with MJPEG, I think

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using ffmpeg, I have no idea how your wrapper does this, but using the ffmpeg command line you can do this

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/my/frame.png temp_out.mp4

echo "file path/to/my/video.mp4" >> concat.txt    
echo "file temp_out.mp4" >> concat.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy path/to/my/output.mp4
```

this encodes the frame (not the video) into a .mp4 and then concats that .mp4 onto your existing .mp4, feel free to adjust the duration of the temp_out.mp4 using the -t parameter

Comment: I already tried ffmpeg but neither it being created a zero byte file or nothing at all.

Comment: I literally ran those exact commands (beside the paths) this command works

Comment: Then what am i doing wrong that it's not working for me?
-loop 1 -i a.jpg -t 1 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1920:1080 temp_out.mp4 && echo \"file video.mp4\" >> concat.txt && echo \"file temp_out.mp4\" >> concat.txt && ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy output.mp4

Comment: i have updated the args, to remove a bit of clutter, could you try those new commands / give me an example file that does not work for you?